# Return (an empty string) after POST Ajax using Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

this is my html javascript

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'post.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: 'name="dan"',
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error');
        }   
    });
```

and here is the post.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "test";
$user = "";
$pass = "";

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (MYSQL_ERROR);
$select_db = mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Could not select the database.");

$name = $_POST["name"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO user VALUES (null, '$name')";

mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not execute query.");


?>
```

Successful posted but when I do console.log of result, it shows (an empty string) in firebug. Can anyone help me with this issue please? thanks

I would like to have a return as a JSON type.

Comment: You're not returning anything.

Comment: c'mon - work around : add some conditions `if/else` then do `echo` depending on the ones

Comment: sorry I've just learned php, ajax, and jquery 1 hour ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'post.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {name: "dan"},
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('error');
    }   
});
```

`result` = what is echoed in your `post.php` if nothing is echoed or printed, it returns nothing.

Comment: yep data send in AJAX still confused me as it sent on JSON syntactic . instead of `'name="dane"`' use `name:"dane"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something via `echo`.

Also, i strongly recommend you to read [this](http://www.phptherightway.com/).